# VBA display selection options

Tags: vba, permutation

I am trying to write a code that will display a value depending on what checkbox is selected.  There are a total of 5 checkboxes and I will be adding additional checkboxes in the future so I was wondering if there is an easy way to determine which checkboxes are checked to determine which values to display.  I can do this in a really round about way but I would like minimize my code if possible.

In other words, if i write each scenario out I would have to write a separate code for all of the different selection possbilities:

1 only,2 only,3 only,4 only,5 only

1+2, 1+3, 1+4, 1+5, 2+3, 2+4, 2+5, 3+4, 3+5, 4+5

1+2+3, 1+2+4,1+2+5, 1+3+4,1+3+5, 1+4+5,2+3+4, 2+3+5,3+4+5

1+2+3+4, 1+2+3+5, 1+3+4+5, 2+3+4+5

1+2+3+4+5

Each value is associated with a sub that will fill the array if it is selected.  And after the arrays are filled I need to perform an additional function on the ones that are selected.  The function performed is the same but I do not want to perform the function if a value is not selected because it will defeat the purpose of my function otherwise. The function itself is to select duplicates from the arrays that were selected into another array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [binary numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system) for each checkbox:

- First value is 1 (`=2`<sup>`0`</sup>)
- Second value is 2 (`=2`<sup>`1`</sup>)
- Third value is 4 (`=2`<sup>`2`</sup>)
- Fourth value is 8 (`=2`<sup>`2`</sup>)
- Fifth value is 16 (`=2`<sup>`4`</sup>)

Hence, when you sum each permutation, you have a unique number you can check.

1. 1 only is `0`, 2 only is `1` and so on
2. 1+2 is `3`, 1+3 is `5`, 1+4 is `9`, 1+5 is `17`
3. and so on

You can create arrays with every case you want to check.
At least, i hope this will give you some ideas or tips.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

What @JMax is referring to is more commonly known as [bit-masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_mask).  Here's a quick tutorial:

Create a sample form named Form1 with 5 checkboxes named Check1, Check2, Check3, Check4, Check5.  Then add the following two functions in a standard code module:

```
Function GetSelectedBoxes() As Long
Dim Ctl As Control, Total As Long

    For Each Ctl In Forms!form1
        If Ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
            If Ctl Then
                Total = Total + 2 ^ CLng(Mid(Ctl.Name, 6))
            End If
        End If
    Next Ctl
    GetSelectedBoxes = Total
End Function

Sub ShowSelectedBoxes()
Dim Total As Long, i As Integer
    Total = GetSelectedBoxes
    For i = 1 To 5
        If Total And 2 ^ i Then Debug.Print "Check" & i & " selected"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Now open Form1 and check boxes 1, 3, and 4.  Run the ShowSelectedBoxes routine and you should get the following output in the immediate window:

```
Check1 selected
Check3 selected
Check4 selected
```

I used the `For...Loop` for compactness in my sample, but you can just as easily break it out into separate `If...Then` statements to do something more meaningful with the checked boxes.

This approach will support up to 31 or 32 separate checkboxes.